# Android Studio Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, java, ros

I imported a working project to Android Studio and it builds just fine. When I compile it and send it to my device it goes there, but quits every time I try to launch it without showing any elements. I suspect the problem is with rendering. When I go to main.xml i get this error

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- org.ros.android.view.VirtualJoystickView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
- org.ros.android.view.visualization.VisualizationView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project
```

This is my main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.ros.android.view.visualization.VisualizationView
        android:id="@+id/visualization"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <org.ros.android.view.VirtualJoystickView
        android:id="@+id/virtual_joystick"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the classed mentioned on your build path?